# Automatically fix naming rule violation with JsonProperty in Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there any tool to automate a very big but repetetive task?

```
public class Food
{
     public string name {get; set;} // warning Naming rule violation
}
```

the manual fix:

```
public class Food
{
     [JsonProperty("name")]
     public string Name{get; set;} // no warning => correct name
}
```

Now imagine  having to do thousands of this, of course I could do that in a couple of hours, but maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@burning_LEGION provided a good answer.

If you're generating your classes from an existing JSON you can also use an automatic generator, that will create your classes.

In most of these you can check PascalCase and Json-Property PropertyAttributes:
[image]

Then you will achieve the following: ( Tested with https://json2csharp.com/ and https://www.jsonutils.com/)

### Input

```
{ food: { name: "test" } }
```

### Output

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Food    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        [JsonProperty("food")]
        public Food Food { get; set; } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in Startup.cs

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
```